# Information on how to geospatial

Tags: azure-mobile-services

Does Azure Mobile App support geospatial search.

Example I want to store location of shops and search the nearest based on the mobile device location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Mobile Apps does not support geospatial search.

Specifically, the LINQ provider (nor the Node queryjs provider which provides the same functionality for Node applications) supports "NEAR" or "WITHIN POLYGON" functionality.  This is required before you can really say you support Geospatial data.